# Getting a value form "get and set" in java

Tags: java

I have a school problem that I'm stuck on. The problem is that the gross pay keeps coming up as 0.0.

***Here's the question:***

Design a Payroll class  with the following fields:

• name : a String  containing the employee's name 
• idNumber: an int  representing the employee's ID number
• rate: a double  containing the employee's hourly pay rate
• hours: an int  representing the number of hours this employee has worked

The class  should also have the following methods :

• Constructor : takes the employee's name  and ID number as arguments 
• Accessors: allow access to all of the fields of the Payroll class 
• Mutators: let the user assign  values  to the fields of the Payroll class 
• grossPay: returns the employee's gross pay, which is calculated as the number of 
hours worked times the hourly pay rate.

Write another program  that demonstrates the class  by creating a Payroll object , then
asking the user to enter the data for an employee in the order: name , ID number, rate, hours.
The program  should then print out a statement  in the following format (for example, if
you had an employee named  Chris Jacobsen with ID number 11111, who works for 5 hours at 
$10/hr):

Chris Jacobsen, employee number 11111, made $50.00 in gross pay.

Using text forming so that the gross pay is rounded to two decimal places.

***Here's what I have so far:***

```
         import java.util.Scanner;

     public class Payroll
     {
        private String EmployeeName;
        private int IDnumber;
        private double HourlyPayRate;
        private double TotalHoursWorked;
        private double TotalGrossPay;

        public Payroll(String Name, int ID, double HourlyRate, double HoursWorked)
        {
            EmployeeName = Name;
            IDnumber = ID;
        }
        public String getEmployeeName()
        {
            return EmployeeName;
        }
        public int getIDnumber()
        {
            return IDnumber;
        }
        public void setHourlyPayRate(double HourlyRate)
        {
            HourlyPayRate = HourlyRate;
        }
        public double getHourlyPayRate()
        {
            return HourlyPayRate;
        }
        public void setTotalHoursWorked(double HoursWorked)
        {
            TotalHoursWorked = HoursWorked;
        }
        public double getTotalHoursWorked()
        {
            return TotalHoursWorked;
        }
        public void setTotalGrossPay(double GrossPay)
        {
            TotalGrossPay = GrossPay;
        }
        public double getTotalGrossPay(double HourlyRate, double HoursWorked)
        {
            TotalGrossPay = HourlyRate * HoursWorked;
           return TotalGrossPay;
        }


        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            String EmployeeName;
            int IDnumber;
            double TotalHoursWorked;
            double HourlyPayRate;
            double TotalGrossPay;

           Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("Enter employee's name:");
            EmployeeName = keyboard.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Enter employee's ID number:" );
            IDnumber = keyboard.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Enter hourly rate:");
            HourlyPayRate = keyboard.nextDouble();

            System.out.print("Enter number of hours worked:");
            TotalHoursWorked = keyboard.nextDouble();

            Payroll pay = new Payroll(EmployeeName, IDnumber, HourlyPayRate, TotalHoursWorked);

            System.out.print(EmployeeName + ", " + "employee number " + IDnumber + ", made $" + 
           pay.TotalGrossPay + " in gross pay.");
       }
  }
```

Thanks for any help...

Comment: What are you providing as input?

Comment: You missed the call to method getTotalGrossPay. Don't use pay.TotalGrossPay (because that will return the current value which is set to 0 by default) instead do this pay. getTotalGrossPay()

Comment: you must call your method instead of pay. getTotalGrossPay and your method must be static or define instance for pay class in your main mehod...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TotalGrossPay` is a calculated value, unless you call the methods to calculate it, it will remain as its default value (`0`)

The fact is, you shouldn't be storing this value anyway, as it's value is actually determine by the calculation of the other fields.

Remove the `TotalGrossPay` field from your class and write a simple "getter" that calculates the value and returns it...

```
public double getTotalGrossPay()
{
    return HourlyRate * HoursWorked;
}
```

As a general rule of thumb, you should not be accessing fields directly, but should always be accessing their values (setting/getting) via methods

Also, don't ignore values passed to your constructor...

```
public Payroll(String Name, int ID, double HourlyRate, double HoursWorked)
{
    EmployeeName = Name;
    IDnumber = ID;
    // What about HourlyRate and HoursWorked??
}
```

Either make the user supply these vai setters or assign them within your constructor (and yes, you could use the setters to change the values after the fact...)

```
public Payroll(String Name, int ID, double HourlyRate, double HoursWorked)
{
    EmployeeName = Name;
    IDnumber = ID;
    this.HourlyRate = HourlyRate;
    this.HoursWorked = HoursWorked;
}
```

You might like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

Answer (score 2):

in your constructor you are not doing anything with  HourlyRate and HoursWorked

```
public Payroll(String Name, int ID, double HourlyRate, double HoursWorked)
```

Why is your getter taking parameters  you need to rename it to something like `calculateGrossPay()`. Remove them and use the instance members `HourlyRate` and `HoursWorked` to calculate total gross pay. This is why you are getting a 0.0 as a result

**Another point worth noting here is , double variable when uninitialized is set to 0.0 by Java**

```
public double getTotalGrossPay(double HourlyRate, double HoursWorked)
```

Comment: Or better yet, remove the parameters from the getter.

Comment: was just editing the post when you commented. Using my mobile which is slowing me down